# orWhere giving unexpected result

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to search pages whose lang_id = 1, I am using following laravel query

```
$result =  $this->where('lang_id', $this->langId );
$result->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
       ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
$result->get();
```

It gives me pages having lang_id other than 1 too.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you build your query to return all records that have this lang_id and title, OR description starting with some search keyword. And that's why you get another results, because some of them don't meet the lang_id requirement, but they meet the description match.

You need to group your where conditions properly, like this:

```
$result =  $this->where('lang_id', $this->langId )
->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
});
$result->get();
```

This is equal to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lang_id = $lang_id AND (
    title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%'
)
```

Comment: thank you for helping still there is a mistake we need to pass use $search otherwise it gives exception.